# Adding login to right top corner

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to add login to right top corner, just like most forums have. I split my container on left/right, but the right side wouldn't work.

```
    <div id="header">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="leftbox">
            LOGO image
            </div>
<div class="rightbox">
 <form class="form-signin">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>

        <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>

        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
          </label>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
      </form>

</div>
```

css

```
body {
    background-color: #E3E3E3;
    font-size: 12px;
} 

h1, 
h2, 
h3, 
h4, 
h5, 
h6 {
    color: #4f4f4f;
    font-family: "BebasNeue", sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
}

/* header/navbar*/

#header{
    background-color: #2C2C2C;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-top: 30px;
}

#header.leftbox{
    float:left;
    display: inline;
}

#header.rightbox{
    float:right;
    display: inline;
    width: 200px;
}
```

here is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/otj12jno/

Comment: What exactly do you want to move?

Comment: login form to right

Comment: `#header.leftbox` selects `<div id="header" class"leftbox">`. I think you want `#header .leftbox` and `#header .rightbox` (note the spaces). See [Descendant Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made one mistake. There should be a space between id and class in css.

```
#header.leftbox{}
```

This code calls element which `id="header"` and `class="leftbox"`

```
#header .leftbox{}
```

This code calls element which `class="leftbox"` and his parent (or grandparent etc.) has `id="header"`

Comment: didn't know that, ty

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to use `position: absolute` on the button class and then set position as follows:

```
#signinbtnClass {
 position : absolute;
 top : 0 px  // or below the header or banner image
 left :10px;
}
```